External disk shows space occupied but not listing all the files
Running:
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
/dev/sdb1 (the external disk) is formatted as NTFS.
sfdisk output is here
$ sudo sfdisk -l  /dev/sdb1
[sudo] password for user: 
Disk /dev/sdb1: 1.82 TiB, 2000363192320 bytes, 3906959360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x73736572

Device      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1p1      1920221984 3736432267 1816210284   866G 72 unknown
/dev/sdb1p2      1936028192 3889681299 1953653108 931.6G 6c unknown
/dev/sdb1p3               0          0          0     0B  0 Empty
/dev/sdb1p4        27722122   27722568        447 223.5K  0 Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Output of parted
 sudo parted -l  /dev/sdb1
Model: WD My Passport 2626 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name         Flags
 1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  ntfs         My Passport  msftdata


Model: WD PC SN740 SDDQMQD-512G-1201 (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   512GB  512GB  ext4


Have been using this disk for more than year never encountered this kind of issue. Today restarted the system without unmounting/disconnecting the disk and this issue appeared.
df -h and du -sch are both run on the mount point of the external disk
Only some of my directories are visible.
I'm running both commands at the root directory of the disk:
/media/username/My Passport 
df -h returns correct space occupied.
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       1.9T  719G  1.2T  39% /media/username/My Passport

du -sch shows only 400GB. 330GB is missing.
401G    ./
401G    total

Any ideas how to recover that?
Disk space 770GB:

All files space occupied only 430GB:


Your two commands look at very different things; your second commands was incomplete as no specific location was provided, thus it used $PWD, where you've provided no context so we can't know what it actually is showing.

Thanks. I am updating the question. The location was the root of the disk.

Your question still doesn't provide details of $PWD in regards to the du command, as context is required as to what is installed; but it's still different. If I use df to view partitions; I'll see a 96GB partition for my / on this box; yet if I use du it'll show disk usage which results in 23TB; as mounts are shown in the du which in my case involves NFS or network shares where I store data that wouldn't fit on my small SSD.  Your question gives no details about your system, (what Ubuntu product/release) nor your actual setup; contextual details of what you're comparing.

I'm not an expert, but maybe your you formatted the disk on a Windows machine and you're trying to inspect it from Ubuntu, which could be buggy in a few cases. But as @guiverc mentioned, you should provide more details on the system you're running. I'd also suggest providing the partition type of /dev/sdb1, and the partition table of the disk.
